# Loading BlackBerry application from command line

Tags: blackberry, build-automation

I am following the instruction from "[Using the BlackBerry Smartphone Simulator programmatically](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6338/Using_the_BBSmrtphnSmltr_programmatically_607582_11.jsp)" to load a .cod file from the command line using fledgecontroller commands.  I am calling `LoadCod(D:\Sample.cod)` and nothing happens; the application does not install on the simulator. However if I manually browse and load the cod from the simulator's “file->Load Java Program” option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error message at all?
If I try a similar thing (have a cod in C:\Sample.cod, connect using fledge and attempt LoadCod(C:\Sample.cod)) I get the following error message -

Jvm: could not open C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry Smartphone Simulators 4.5.0\4.5.0.55 (8310)\sample.cod

I moved the sample.cod to that directory and it worked okay. If you get no error message I am not sure what the problem is. Are you definitely connected to the correct simulator session? What simulator and OS version are you using?

Comment: "Are you definitely connected to the correct simulator session? What simulator and OS version are you using?"- Yes